# Is Fragment can contain NavController?

Tags: android, navigation

I want to use Fragment like a hostFragment. It contains

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that.
I did it using this code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextTitles" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cameraController"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_cameras" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and code in your fragment (I'm using Kotlin):

```
val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.your_fragment_id)
val toolbar = requireActivity().findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
rootDestination = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.myFirstNavFragment))
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, rootDestination)
```

Hope this code could help you!

Comment: Android Studio notify error when I use requireActivity().findNavController, it can't compiled :( I use navigationVersion = "2.1.0".

Comment: @HienNguyen - `requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.your_fragment_id)` uses a Kotlin extension in the `-ktx` artifacts (so make sure you're using `navigation-fragment-ktx` if you're using Kotlin). You'd want to use `Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.your_fragment_id)` if you're in Java.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't be calling `setGraph()` if you're using `app:navGraph` - `app:navGraph` is calling `setGraph` itself and you don't want to reset your navigation by calling it again.

Comment: :( not working yet. Please help me again, is the above xml snippet in activity xml or fragment xml ? Could u post full snippet for me please ? :(

Comment: @HienNguyen yes, it's in a fragment. I'll edit my answer with full xml.

Comment: I will try again :*